Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle' error during app bundle build in android studio
App bundle gives the below error. I have tried all previous stackflow solutions to the same error but none seem to work.
`PS D:\refereevision> flutter build appbundle          
Resolving dependencies... 
  _flutterfire_internals 1.3.24 (1.3.30 available)
  chewie 1.7.1 (1.8.1 available)
  firebase_core 2.26.0 (2.30.0 available)
  firebase_core_web 2.11.5 (2.15.0 available)
  firebase_performance 0.9.3+16 (0.9.4+2 available)
  firebase_performance_platform_interface 0.1.4+24 (0.1.4+30 available)
  firebase_performance_web 0.1.4+24 (0.1.6+2 available)
  flutter_animate 4.1.1+1 (4.5.0 available)
  flutter_lints 3.0.0 (3.0.2 available)
  flutter_native_splash 2.3.1 (2.4.0 available)
  font_awesome_flutter 10.6.0 (10.7.0 available)
  go_router 12.1.3 (13.2.4 available)
  google_fonts 6.1.0 (6.2.1 available)
! http 1.2.0 (overridden) (1.2.1 available)
  image 4.0.17 (4.1.7 available)
  intl 0.18.1 (0.19.0 available)
  iregexp 0.1.1 (0.1.2 available)
  js 0.6.7 (0.7.1 available)
  json_path 0.6.2 (0.7.1 available)
  leak_tracker 10.0.0 (10.0.5 available)
  leak_tracker_flutter_testing 2.0.1 (3.0.5 available)
  leak_tracker_testing 2.0.1 (3.0.1 available)
  material_color_utilities 0.8.0 (0.11.1 available)
  meta 1.11.0 (1.14.0 available)
  package_info_plus 5.0.1 (7.0.0 available)
  package_info_plus_platform_interface 2.0.1 (3.0.0 available)
  path_provider 2.0.14 (2.1.3 available)
  path_provider_android 2.0.25 (2.2.4 available)
  path_provider_foundation 2.2.2 (2.3.2 available)
  path_provider_linux 2.1.11 (2.2.1 available)
  path_provider_platform_interface 2.0.6 (2.1.2 available)
  path_provider_windows 2.1.7 (2.2.1 available)
  petitparser 5.4.0 (6.0.2 available)
  photo_view 0.14.0 (0.15.0 available)
! pointer_interceptor 0.10.1 (overridden)
  pointer_interceptor_web 0.10.1+2 (0.10.2 available)
  pointycastle 3.8.0 (3.9.0 available)
  provider 6.0.5 (6.1.2 available)
  rfc_6901 0.1.1 (0.2.0 available)
  shared_preferences 2.2.2 (2.2.3 available)
  shared_preferences_android 2.2.1 (2.2.2 available)
  shared_preferences_foundation 2.3.4 (2.3.5 available)
  shared_preferences_platform_interface 2.3.1 (2.3.2 available)
  shared_preferences_web 2.2.1 (2.3.0 available)
  sqflite 2.2.6 (2.3.3 available)
  test_api 0.6.1 (0.7.1 available)
  timeago 3.2.2 (3.6.1 available)
  url_launcher 6.2.5 (6.2.6 available)
  url_launcher_android 6.3.0 (6.3.1 available)
  url_launcher_web 2.2.3 (2.3.1 available)
! uuid 4.4.0 (overridden)
  video_player 2.8.1 (2.8.6 available)
  video_player_android 2.4.10 (2.4.14 available)
  video_player_avfoundation 2.5.1 (2.5.7 available)
  video_player_platform_interface 6.2.1 (6.2.2 available)
  video_player_web 2.1.2 (2.3.0 available)
  vm_service 13.0.0 (14.2.1 available)
  wakelock_plus 1.1.4 (1.2.4 available)
  web 0.4.2 (0.5.1 available)
  webview_flutter_android 3.15.0 (3.16.0 available)
  webview_flutter_wkwebview 3.12.0 (3.13.0 available)
  xml 6.3.0 (6.5.0 available)
  youtube_player_iframe_web 2.0.2 (3.0.2 available)
Got dependencies!
61 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.

Font asset "CupertinoIcons.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 257628 to 1832 bytes (99.3% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Font asset "fa-solid-900.ttf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 394668 to 1804 bytes (99.5% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.
Font asset "MaterialIcons-Regular.otf" was tree-shaken, reducing it from 1645184 to 3032 bytes (99.8% reduction). Tree-shaking can be disabled by providing the --no-tree-shake-icons flag when building your app.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
   > java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 34s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                             94.8s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
PS D:\refereevision> `

The following changes made to build.gradle

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

   signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now,
            // so `flutter run --release` works.
                      signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }


dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0-rc01'
}

The key.properties file is in android folder
The keystore file is in root directory of project
Kindly help
Tried the following

cleared cache
deleted .gradle file
restarted AS
Started build

